# Function not returning desired string

Tags: c++, string, function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
string wordB(string input);

int main() {
    //ask for word
    cout << "Enter a word\n";

    //get word
    string input = "";
    cin >> input;

    //return with b in between all letters
    cout << wordB(input);
    cout << endl << input;
}

string wordB(string str) {
    string rString = "";

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
        rString += "B" + str.at(i);
    }
    cout << endl << rString;

    return rString;
}
```

Trying to display the word a users enter where between every character there is the letter "B".  When I run this with the word `"join"` I get back `"trtr"`.

Comment: Undefined behaviour.   `str.at(i)` is an integral value.   `"B" + n` where `n` is an integral value accesses the `n`th character of the string literal `"B"`.   Since the string literal `"B"` is represented as an array of two `char`, any value of `n` less than zero or more than `1` falls off the end.   Your code appends the result of all that to `rString`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`"B" + str.at(i);` doesn't do what you seem to think it does; it's not string conctatenation. It says: take a `char*` pointer pointing to the beginning of the string literal `"B"`, advance it by the number of characters equal to the ASCII code of character `str.at(i)`, and treat the resulting pointer as pointing to a nul-terminated string. Unless `str.at(i)` happens to be `'\x0'` or `'\x1'` (unlikely), your program exhibits undefined behavior.

There are many different ways to do what you want. Here's one:

```
rString.push_back('B');
rString.push_back(str[i]);
```

Comment: Or `rString += "B" + str.substr(i, 1);`

Answer (score 2):

A particularly nice fix, available from C++14 onwards, is to write

```
rString += "B"s + str.at(i);
```

noting the `s`, which is a *user-defined literal*. That then forces the overloaded `+` operator on `std::string` to be used, rather than the built-in `+`, which is actually performing dubious (and potentially undefined) *pointer arithmetic* on the `const char[2]` literal `"B"` decayed to a `const char*`.

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly it is a pitfall... in this line

```
rString += "B" + str.at(i);
```

the `"B" + str.at(i)` part is not doing what one might expect: It adds `str.at(i)` to a `char` pointer (pointing to the first letter of "B"). The fix is easy:

```
rString += std::string("B") + str.at(i);
                        //  ^-------------- now calls the correct operator
```

Just as a curiosity consider this:

```
(rString += "B") += str.at(i);
```

I do not recommend to write it (its too obfuscated), but it does the right thing, because there is a `std::string::operator+(char*)` and a `std::string::operator+(char)`.

Comment: I'd recommend using stringstream

Comment: @smac89: Why, out of interest?

Comment: @Bathsheba Looks cleaner IMO: `ss << 'B' << str.at(i)`

Comment: @smac89: But then you have all the `.str()` nonsense as well as the declaration. Personally I prefer the tools offered by C++14.

Comment: @Bathsheba good point, but you only get to do the `.str()` at the end, not between concatenations

Comment: @smac89 I am with Bathsheba, I dont like the boilerplate that comes with stringstream. But there is still room for another answer ;) go ahead and add it. The more different answers, the better

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is as a result of [`order of evaluation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order).

The `+=` operator will force the right-hand-side of the expression to be evaluated and the result will be appended to the string.

This is what causes the problem you are facing because the right-hand-side is not `std::string`, and therefore the meaning of the `+` operator in that rhs simply translates to pointer arithemetic not string concatenation as you would expect.

A simple fix is to be more explicit and do this:

```
rString = rString + "B" + str.at(i);
```

This will now cause the compiler to first evaluate the right-hand-side of the `=` operator as a string and then you get concatenation. It also gives the added benefit of allowing the compiler to inform you if the right-hand side is not a string.

---

Another alternative is to use string streams. I think it looks cleaner so here it is:

```
#include <sstream>
...

string wordB(string str) {
    std::ostringstream oss;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
        oss << 'B' << str.at(i);
    }
    cout << endl << oss.str();

    return oss.str();
}
```